# Django_tagging (v0.3/pre): Configuration issue

Tags: python, django, django-admin, tagging

I am trying to use the django-tagging in one of my project and run into some errors.

I can play with tags in the shell but couldn't assign them from admin interface.

What I want to do is add "tag" functionality to a model and add/remove tags from Admin interface.

Why is it the "tags" are seen by shell and not by "admin" interface? What is going on?

Model.py:

```
import tagging

class Department(models.Model):
    tags = TagField()
```

Admin.py:

```
class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'tags') --> works
....
    fields = ['name', 'tags'] --> throws error
```

Error

```
    OperationalError at /admin/department/1/
    (1054, "Unknown column 'schools_department.tags' in 'field list'")
```

I looked at the docs and couldn't find further information
[Useful Tips](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/wiki/UsefulTips)
[Overview Txt](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/source/browse/trunk/docs/overview.txt)

Answer (score 4):

The TagField requires an actual database column on your model; it uses this to cache the tags as entered. If you add a TagField to a model that already has a database table, you will need to add the column to the database table, just as with adding any other type of field. Either use a schema migration tool (like South or django-evolution) or run the appropriate SQL ALTER TABLE command manually.

Comment: I thought the tags are stored in 'tagging_taggeditem' as this will have a 1:n relationship with tagged item? I can see the tags are stored in this table referring the tags and the object_id. Will test it anyway.

Comment: No it didn't change the eror.

Comment: Tags are stored in tagging_taggeditem with a 1:n relationship, just as you say. Also, a TagField stores the tags as entered as a plain string in the database. Yes, it's denormalized, but that's how it works; you can check the code. And that error is clearly complaining that the schools_department table is missing the "tags" column, so if you're still getting the error, I have to think you didn't do the ALTER TABLE correctly.

Comment: I added the tags column in schools_department table but still get the same error. What I want to do is to add tags from the admin site. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Sorry, not really. All the code you have pasted looks fine, I have practically identical code running here (only difference is I generally use fieldsets rather than fields in the ModelAdmin, so I guess you could try that). The error still looks to me like MySQL complaining about a missing column in the table, but if you've addressed that? No idea.